# On-topic? Wikimedia Labs platform

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Wikimedia Labs is a bit like Heroku (for which we have 167 questions), but restricted to Wikimedia-related activities.

People can create/manage instances.
[Puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29) is used for almost everything, and all configuration (except passwords) is [open](http://git.wikimedia.org/tree/operations/puppet.git).
Despite having "Labs" in the name, the platform is used for live production, for instance serving web requests, executing data tasks, etc.

So, if I have a well-researched question about a Puppet deployment to Wikimedia Labs, is it on-topic or off-topic here?

Comment: Ask the question and see what the community thinks.

Comment: Are you talking about [Wikimedia Labs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Labs)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Thanks, fixed!

Comment: Nicolas, whilst Iain's comment is pragmatic and not wrong, +1 from me for bothering to try to get a handle on SF's ethos before posting; most polite, somewhat uncommon, and much appreciated by me.

Answer (score 7):

We generally like good Puppet questions here.

The fact that it's destined for Wikimedia Labs might be a gray area though. As you're probably aware, Server Fault is a site for *professional* system administration, and some people might consider Wikimedia's unique development and operations processes as not quite "professional" (for some definition of professional).

I personally wouldn't consider such a question off topic for that reason alone, though I might consider not mentioning Wikimedia Labs in the question itself unless it was important to understanding the question.

The wide applicability of such a question to a professional Puppet-using audience will weigh in your favor.